# parsing Gradle exception messages from a text file

Tags: python, parsing, gradle

I have a Gradle build exception message like the one below in a text file

```
 "Error code is 1\nCommand line is: output/googlesamples/android-> ActionBarCompat-Basic/head/gradlew --stacktrace -p output/googlesamples/android-ActionBarCompat-Basic/head assembleDebug\n\n\nFAILURE: Build failed with an exception.\n\n\n\n* Where:\n\nBuild file '/...../output/googlesamples/android-ActionBarCompat-Basic/head/Application/build.gradle' line: 12\n\n\n\n* What went wrong:\n\nA problem occurred evaluating project ':Application'.\n\n> Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.application']\n\n   > Gradle version 2.10 is required. Current version is 2.8. If using the gradle wrapper
```

Are there any libraries in python which I could make use of to parse this exception message and obtain individual parts of it ?

> **eg:** Error Code, Command line, FAILURE, etc ?.

Comment: Might look into Logstash

Comment: @WayneWerner thanks ! will try it out. Also came across something called **Graylog**.

Comment: You could probably get a lot just using python's `re` module...